# What am I doing wrong with this BC7 reading?

Tags: directx11, dds

I need to import a BCn image without any existing libraries. Thus, I have to write my own reader. This has gone fairly well so far for BCs 1-5 (don't need BC6), but now BC7 is causing a problem.

As testing, I have a BC7 image that I know to have an entirely empty blue channel, and the very first 4x4 block is all solid red (rgba 255,0,0,255). This is the data of that block, as read directly from the file:

```
as hex: 30FF0300 C0FFAFAA AAAA4A92 24499224
as bin: 00110000111111110000001100000000110000001111111110101111101010101010101010101010010010101001001000100100010010011001001000100100
```

According to [the standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/bc7-format), this is a mode 2 block (starts with 001), which means this is the decoding pattern:

[image: BC7 mode 2 pattern]

This lays out how the endpoints are stored in the order all reds, all greens, all blues. Simple compared to most other modes. But when I lay out the bits like this, I get this structure:

```
mode:         001
partition ID: 100001
reds:         11111 11000 00011 00000 00011 00000
greens:       01111 11111 01011 11101 01010 10101
blues:        01010 10101 00100 10101 00100 10001
indexes:      0 01 00 0 10 01 00 11 00 10 01 00 01 00 10 0
```

**Why does the blue channel have no endpoints equal to 0?** The image has no blue whatsoever. And this block doesn't have any green either, yet its endpoints are also all nonzero. If I swap the reading from RRRRRRGGGGGGBBBBBB to RRGGBBRRGGBBRRGGBB, that would at least get a zero endpoint in each channel, but this wouldn't solve the problem because the non-zero endpoints are still being used at least once (by the definition of mode 2). And furthermore, there are only 3 strings of 5+ zeroes in the entire input, all of which are in the red zone, so it's not like I'm only a bit or two off or something. I can't see any possible way to read this data that makes logical sense while still remaining true to the stated standard.

I haven't needed to do any messing about with endians or such bit/byte-order-changing for the other BCn readers, so I shouldn't need to for this.

EDIT: I have done some messing about with editing the image binary directly and seeing what this affects when opened in Visual Studio or XNViewMP. And apparently, editing the bits that are supposed to be the red endpoints instead affects the alpha of the block. Mode 2 is supposed to be opaque, and in none of the modes does alpha come before colour - maybe it gets swapped with a colour, but the alpha is apparently also immediately followed by the red, so it cannot be a swap. So I'm now suspicious that this can't be a BC7 image at all, despite all the exiting programs labelling it as such.

Comment: According to the [Khronos docs](https://registry.khronos.org/DataFormat/specs/1.3/dataformat.1.3.html#table-bptcmodebits), your general layout looks correct.

Comment: You may find looking at the source code for [texdiag](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/main/Texdiag/texdiag.cpp) useful. Start on line 2888.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Khronos docs](https://registry.khronos.org/DataFormat/specs/1.3/dataformat.1.3.html#table-bptcmodebits) linked in the comment, I think you've got the mode wrong:

> Each block can contain data in one of eight modes. The mode is identified by the lowest bits of the lowest byte. It is encoded as zero or more zeros followed by a one. For example, using ‘x’ to indicate a bit not included in the mode number, mode 0 is encoded as xxxxxxx1 in the low byte in binary, mode 5 is xx100000, and mode 7 is 10000000. Encoding the low byte as zero is reserved and should not be used when encoding a BPTC texture; hardware decoders processing a texel block with a low byte of 0 should return 0 for all channels of all texels.

Your first byte is `0x30` or `00110000b` which looks to me like it decodes as mode 4 according to those instructions, because it ends with four zeros in binary.

Obviously that means that you also need to change the way that you've looked at the rest of the data in the block.

Comment: Does this imply that every other byte also has to be read backwards? Because that would be weird and not aligned with all the other BCn formats.

Comment: Correction (can't edit comment older than 5 minutes): It wouldn't be aligned with what I happen to have working for the other BCn formats. It's possible there's something sneaky happening in the background that obscured the reversal.

Comment: I am getting improved results now, so I'm accepting this answer.